# Serialize and deserialize binary tree with a lot of empty nodes

Tags: python, python-2.x, tree, serialization

Here is my code to serialize and deserialize binary tree, which may have a lot of empty nodes. I am written in Python 2.7. Any advice on performance improvement in terms of algorithm time complexity, bugs or code style advice is appreciated.

My major idea is, serialize only non-empty nodes, with node ID information, where `left node ID * 2 = parent node ID`, and `right node ID * 2 + 1 = parent node ID`

**Source code in Python 2.7**,

```
from collections import defaultdict
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value, left, right):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def serialize_tree(self, result):
        stack = []
        stack.append((self, 1))
        while len(stack) > 0:
            node, index = stack.pop(0)
            result.append((node.value, index))
            if node.left:
                stack.append((node.left, index*2))
            if node.right:
                stack.append((node.right, index*2+1))
    @staticmethod
    def deserialize_tree(source):
        result = []
        for (node_value, index) in source:
            node = TreeNode(node_value, None, None)
            result.append(node)
            if index == 1:
                continue
            elif index % 2 == 0:
                result[index / 2 - 1].left = node
            else:
                result[(index - 1) / 2 - 1].right = node
        return result[0]
    def print_tree(self, result):
        result.append(self.value)
        if self.left:
            self.left.print_tree(result)
        else:
            result.append('#')
        if self.right:
            self.right.print_tree(result)
        else:
            result.append('#')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2, None, TreeNode(4, None, None)), TreeNode(3, None, None))
    result = []
    root.serialize_tree(result)
    print result
    new_root = TreeNode.deserialize_tree(result)
    result2 = []
    new_root.print_tree(result2)
    print result2
```

Comment: Do you have the following requirements: (1) the tree is a binary search tree (i.e. is sorted)? (2) Do you expect the deserialized tree to be of the same shape as the serialized tree?

Comment: @coderodde, good question, no requirement for binary search tree, just a normal binary tree.

Comment: @coderodde, for your question -- "Do you expect the deserialized tree to be of the same shape as the serialized tree", definitely I expect they are the same after serialize, and deserialize, because serialization and deserialization is just like compression, do not want to lose any information. Your idea of my original question is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a map mapping each key of a node \$u\$ in the tree to a 2-tuple containing the key of the parent \$p\$, and a boolean indicating whether \$u\$ is a left or right child of \$p\$:

```
class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key == other.key

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.key


def serialize_tree(root_node):
    map_node_key_to_parent_data = {}

    def serialize_tree_impl(node, parent_node):
        if parent_node:
            parent_data = (parent_node.key, parent_node.left is node)
            map_node_key_to_parent_data[node.key] = parent_data
        else:
            map_node_key_to_parent_data[node.key] = None

        if node.left:
            serialize_tree_impl(node.left, node)

        if node.right:
            serialize_tree_impl(node.right, node)

    serialize_tree_impl(root_node, None)
    return map_node_key_to_parent_data


def deserialize_tree(map_node_key_to_parent_data):
    map_node_key_to_tree_node = {}

    for node_key in map_node_key_to_parent_data.keys():
        if node_key not in map_node_key_to_tree_node.keys():
            map_node_key_to_tree_node[node_key] = TreeNode(node_key)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Duplicate node in the tree.")

    root_node = None

    for node_key, parent_data in map_node_key_to_parent_data.items():
        node = map_node_key_to_tree_node[node_key]

        if not parent_data:
            root_node = node
        else:
            parent_node_key = parent_data[0]
            on_left = parent_data[1]
            parent_node = map_node_key_to_tree_node[parent_node_key]

            if on_left:
                parent_node.left = node
            else:
                parent_node.right = node

    return root_node


def binary_search_trees_are_identical(root_node1, root_node2):
    if not root_node1 and not root_node2:
        return True

    if not root_node1 or not root_node2:
        return False

    if root_node1.key != root_node2.key:
        return False

    return binary_search_trees_are_identical(root_node1.left, root_node2.left)\
        and binary_search_trees_are_identical(root_node2.right, root_node2.right)


def main():
    root_node = TreeNode(5);
    l = TreeNode(3)
    r = TreeNode(7)
    rr = TreeNode(10)
    lr = TreeNode(4)
    rrl = TreeNode(11)
    rr.left = rrl

    root_node.left = l
    root_node.right = r
    l.right = lr
    r.right = rr

    serialized_tree = serialize_tree(root_node)
    print serialized_tree

    deserialized_tree_root_node = deserialize_tree(serialized_tree)
    print "Trees are identical:", binary_search_trees_are_identical(root_node, deserialized_tree_root_node)
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**A bug?**

On

```
root = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2, TreeNode(3, TreeNode(4, TreeNode(5, None, None), None), None), None), None)
```

I get an IndexError.

Hope that helps.